# How to generate and add an unique number to a specific virtual product?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to create a simple membership where I create a virtual product that represents a membership card. So I only have one membership-card product.

I will provide a tangible membership card when the customer visits for the first time. By hand, I like to fill in the unique generated number when a membership card is purchased. The customer needs to see the unique number in the confirmation email.

Any tips, ideas about where to start?

Comment: You could provide an array (custom field) with a series of unique numbers and each time a customer purchases a membership card, assign the unique number to the card and the order so that the customer receives the number via e-mail immediately after the purchase.

You can also, if the card has already been purchased, enter the number (via a custom field) while the purchase is 'on hold' and if you then place the order on 'completed' send an e-mail to the customer that his membership card has been finished specifying the number. What do you prefer? what conditions must the unique number meet?

Comment: hmm, trying to understand what you mean. With custom field do you mean the tab "advance_product_data" when editing a product? I have now add a custom field CardNr and gave it the value [%rndCardNr%]. And now I need a woocommerce function hook after-succes-full purchase which replace  [%rndCardNr%] with a number out of the Array, right??

Comment: You should edit your question to answer the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)", as they will help you decide how best to generate unique identifiers. For example, the numbers you want to generate appear to identify membership cards, so that suggests you may have to make those numbers hard to guess, especially if the ID is all someone needs to gain access to memberships.

Comment: @PeterO. that quit an extensive article you have written and a bit overwhelming for my current setup. Answering your article questions:  1? 2Yes 3No 4Yes by me 5Yes, written on card 6Yes
But I might need to rephrase my question as the numbers don't need to random just Unique. So I think a range with numbers 1-100 would be sufficient. I also need to know which woocommerce hook I can use to add a number to a virtual product upon successful payment